# Read Numbers as a String

Tags: c, string, addition, unsigned

The largest number data type that is available in C is the long long which represents a 64-bit number. Using an unsigned long long, you can represent numbers up to around 1×1020 (a 20 digit number). Some times, however, you want to deal with numbers larger than this limit. In this case, you have to develop custom routines to manipulate these numbers.

One way that this can be done is to read these numbers in as strings, and manipulate them digit by digit using the algorithms that you were taught in primary school to perform addition, subtraction etc on paper.

For this assignment, you need to write a C program that accepts two numbers as strings and outputs the sum of these two numbers to the screen. Each of the numbers may be up to 100 digits long.

Comment: Welcome to SO. For a given string, you can read it character by character  (using a condition like take the inputs until we encounter a newline character) and use realloc for dynamic memory allocation. This is just a small outline of the code, so if you want more insights I am happy to help.

Comment: This sounds like a homework, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

The result is as long or one digit longer (so let's go with *"one digit longer"*) than the bigger number of those two. So you need to allocate the space for that.

```
char* x;
char* y;
...
size_t lengthX = strlen(x);
size_t lengthY = strlen(y);
char* z = calloc((max(lengthX, lengthY) + 2), sizeof(char)); //+1 for the digit and +1 for EOS
...
```

Next step is adding every digit of those strings together with carry, fastest way to convert ASCII digit to numerical value is subtracting ASCII table digits offset `'0'`.

```
'0' - '0' = 0 //(48 - 48 = 0)
'1' - '0' = 1 //(49 - 48 = 1)
'2' - '0' = 2 //(50 - 48 = 2)
...
```

And now we can start adding them which will be done in reverse order (assumed `lengthX`  > `lengthY` - if not just swap the values)

```
size_t lengthDiff = lengthX - lengthY;
char result = 0;

for(int i = max(lengthX, lengthY) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if(i >= lengthDiff) //checking if y has enough digits left
    {
        if(result > 9)
            result = x[i] - '0' + y[i - lengthDiff] - '0' + 1; //adding carry
        else 
            result = x[i] - '0' + y[i - lengthDiff] - '0';
    }
    else
    {
        if(result > 9)
            result = x[i] - '0' + 1; //adding carry
        else 
            result = x[i] - '0';
    }
        
    z[i + 1] = result % 10 + '0'; //we don't care right now about carry so let's just take the last digit
}
```

And last thing is to check if last sum had a carry or not

```
if(result > 9)
    z[0] = '1';
else 
    z[0] = '0';
```

And that's it.

Comment: How do you get the max function

Comment: You must write it yourself.